# Scrollable div with header and footer

Tags: html, css

I have a chat template with header (list of chat users, *I don't know height of header, it depend on peoples count, so fixed height is not a deal*) and footer (message textarea field). Between that two divs I want to place messages. Using display: table for parent and display: table-row with 1px height for header and footer works well only in webkit browsers, firefox and IE ignoring that. There's an [example](http://output.jsbin.com/nikedu). Is there way to make working behavior at all browsers (webkit, firefox, IE8+)?

Flexboxes and calc property can't be used because of old browsers support.

Comment: any reason you are still supporting ie8 when microsoft have stopped supporting it?

Comment: Yes, I have some reasons, because of weak computers (even with Windows XP on a board) who will use this chat.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{margin:0;
   padding:0;
   }
body{
 background:#fff; 
 position:absolute; 
 width:100%; 
 height:100%;
 }
.main{
 background:#0C0;
 height:100%; 
 padding:60px 0 40px; 
 box-sizing:border-box;
 }
.header{
 background: #0FC;
 position:absolute; 
 width:100%;
 height:60px;
 }
.left{
 background:#3CC; 
 float:left; 
 width:250px; 
 height:100%; 
 overflow:scroll;
 }
.right{
 background:#9F3; 
 height:100%; 
 overflow:scroll;
 }
.footer{
 background:#9F9; 
 position:absolute; 
 bottom:0; 
 width:100%; 
 height:40px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="left">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
    <div class="right">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: There's no way I could use header with static height, because _it depend on peoples count, so fixed height is not a deal_

Answer (score 0):

@Iworb

I am not understand your full thing but I hope I am close to solve your problem.

[Live View Solution](http://jsbin.com/podegabagu)

You can solve problem by use this CSS:

```
.messages-wrapper .messages-panel #messages-form {
    display: table-row;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**NB:** It's **Supported** all browser .

Comment: This is a full code of chat, that opens in the iframe window. I've implemet your solution into [source](http://jsbin.com/nikedu/edit?html,css,output), but nothing changed. Firefox still looks the same - div with messages with no scroll, but form now appears.

Comment: @Iworb  Thanks I got your update. 

Please add this style also ' width: 100%; '

Comment: Then You will be can see something .

Comment: @Iworb Solve your problem take a look this link 

[Solution Example](http://jsbin.com/podegabagu)

Comment: It still doesn't work on Firefox and IE - there's no scroll for messages div and in webkit browser the last message is behind textarea.

Comment: Sorry I was miss this Issue. Take a Look My another solution.

Answer (score 0):

**@Iworb**

Just take a look:

Solved Your problem By using a simple **jQuery** Function.
    It's supported all browser, I hope.

[Live view](http://jsbin.com/wenupa)

```
var clientHeight = $( window ).height();
var z = clientHeight - '40';
var c = clientHeight - '150';
  $('.conversations-list').css('max-height', z);

  $('.messages-container').css('max-height', c);
```